# change image background position inside a div?

Tags: html, css, image

I want to set a div at 100px by 100px and user an image that's larger than it so it shows a section of it and works like a thumbnail/preview of the full image.

My only problem is that the image starts from top left of the div where as i'd like to have the image about halfway through as there's not a lot going on in the upper left corner so it's a pretty useless thumbnail.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RVd2L/)**

```
.banner-thumbs {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(http://s246027975.websitehome.co.uk/apc_banner_1.png)
}

<div class="banner-thumbs"></div>
```

Comment: Why not just crop it in paint and make it a separate image and link to that one for the thumbnail?

Comment: @AlexPodworny There will be a few images and more I will add over times I'd prefer to just call in the main image and crop it using code instead of doubling my work :)

Comment: take a look at @Cobra_Fast 's answer - i think it's what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use         `background-position:center center;`

```
.banner-thumbs {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-image:url(http://s246027975.websitehome.co.uk/apc_banner_1.png);
        background-position:center center;
    }
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/RVd2L/2/

Comment: You are making me a compliment defining me a scholar. In this profession you never stop learning :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `background-position`.

You could add

```
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

to have the background start at exactly halfway through.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 0):

your can set direction of image ... or say reapet after your image path complete

```
background-image:url('smiley.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on your initial image size, but you can shift the background image by using negative values in the coordinates, such as

```
.banner-thumbs {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:url(http://s246027975.websitehome.co.uk/apc_banner_1.png)
  background-position: -50px -50px;
}
```